# Network Monitor Tun Interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring

I am trying to setup monitoring for my openvpn setup. Everything I have found so far doesn't have good logging for anything but the main network connection.

I already have logging of openvpn data usage etc I just want to be able to monitor each virtual nic as well as the [tun interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82673/what-is-the-tun-network-interface-for) (15 of them) for traffic usage in real time to see traffic peaks, etc. Each tun interface can only handle about 300mbps of traffic, so I want to make sure they are never saturated.

Anyone have any good suggestions? I am only monitoring one server.

Answer (score 1):

I've been pleased with **[symon](http://wpd.home.xs4all.nl/symon/)**, which collects data about network interface usage (as well as other metrics like CPU and memory usage) and displays them in a web interface. Here's an example showing traffic for one network interface for the past week:

[image: Interface traffic graph from symon]

Symon makes it very easy to monitor multiple network interfaces. Your situation might look like this:

```
monitor {
    if(tun0),
    if(tun1),
    # and so on...
} stream to address.of.your.symux.server 2100
```